# How do I uninstall a Chocolatey package and all its dependencies?

Tags: chocolatey

Reading the documentation, it appears that I should be able to install package and its dependencies with the `-x` flag.  But when I try to uninstall the javaruntime package with the command `choco uninstall javaruntime -x`, it fails because of dependencies.

It gives me this error:

```
>  choco uninstall javaruntime -x
Chocolatey v0.10.1
Uninstalling the following packages:
javaruntime
javaruntime not uninstalled. An error occurred during uninstall:
 Unable to uninstall 'javaruntime 8.0.101' because 'groovy 2.3.6' depends on it.

Chocolatey uninstalled 0/1 packages. 1 packages failed.
 See the log for details (C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\logs\chocolatey.log).

Failures
 - javaruntime (exited 1) - javaruntime not uninstalled. An error occurred during uninstall:
 Unable to uninstall 'javaruntime 8.0.101' because 'groovy 2.3.6' depends on it.
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Groovy is not a dependency of JavaRuntime, it has a dependency on JavaRuntime. So if you ran `choco uninstall groovy -x` it would remove javaruntime and then groovy (although javaruntime may fail if other things depend on it). I think we all want a switch to remove something regardless of the things that depend on it.

Answer (score 32):

Try this:

```
choco uninstall webdeploy -x
```

The **webdeploy** can be change to your target package you want to uninstall.

[image]

Comment: where ``-x``, same as the ``--forcedependencies``, ``--removedependencies``. Uninstall dependencies when uninstalling package. Defaults to false.

Comment: The above command force rebooted my PC without confirmation or warning!